# Excel Formula- Divide a sum into multiple cells?

Tags: excel, formula

I need a formula for excel that will allow me to take a sum and divide it up into a number of cells.

for example:

A1= sum

B1 to B4 needs to have a portion of the devided sum

i.e. if sum 1000 then B1=100 B2=200 B3=300 B4=400

Thank's in advance guys

The decomposition rule is that it goes from B1 to B4 in intervals of 100...adding to the pervious

Comment: Thanks for posting your work requirement...

Comment: The sum of B1 to B4 would be in your example 1000 and not 900.

Comment: thanks, the urgency got to me

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the decomposition rule?

Comment: So you mean an arithmetic progression with common difference 100 that sums to whatever is in A1. Are there always 4 terms in the progression?

Comment: exactly, thats what i mean

Answer (score 2):

The formula for the lowest term is `(2 * s / n - (n - 1) * d) / 2` where

```
s is the sum
n the number of terms
d the common difference
```

You have n = 4 and d = 100.

So the lowest term is (s / 2 - 300) / 2.

So if cell A1 contains the sum (1000), you can write =0.5*(A1 / 2 - 300) in cell B1
Then B2 = B1 + 100, B3 = B2 + 100 and B4 = B3 + 100.

The formula comes from the sum of an arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Set alias to cell A1 as amount
2. Use a cell for the number of division which is 4, assume to put in cell A2
3. Calculate the formula for the total portions to divide, put it in cell A3. In your case A3 =A2*(A2+1)/2
4. Set alias to cell A3 as total
5. In each of B columns, set the formula as =(ROW()/total*amount)
6. Copy the formula from step 5 above until the maximum row in B according to your need